# Running Rails generators from my own generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator

I create my own namespaced generator, and I would like to invoke some rails generators ie. model from it. How to accomplish it? I looking also for examples of such code.

Comment: Can you write an example of the command you'd want to write?

Comment: rails g my_scaffold:scaffold Article name:string content:text
I would like provide only controller template, and use rest from rails generators. I know I can override rails scaffold, but I really need to create my own.

Comment: Inheriting from Rails::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator is a good start point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spree's dummy generator we run the `AppGenerator` from within Rails using [this code](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/generators/spree/dummy/dummy_generator.rb#L32-33). This generator is actually [called from within a Rake task called `common:test_app`](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/testing_support/common_rake.rb#L10) which is called when we run `bundle exec rake test_app` at the root of Spree or in the directory for any component of Spree.

I hope this provides you with a decent enough example to get started.

Comment: Hey @Ryan Bigg, maybe you can help me? Im trying to do the same thing but every time i run my generator do i get this error: `Invalid application name white_album, constant WhiteAlbum is already in use. Please choose another application name.` I have found where the error is raised here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb#L268-L269. Do you have any suggestions why this could be?

Comment: I can add, that what I'm trying to do is creating a generator for a test dummy application, very similar to how you (and refinerycms) does it :)